# useFormState vs useForm in Nextjs v14

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation, next.js

Im just trying to understand the use case for using the react hook [useForm](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform) over the react-dom [useFormState](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/hooks/useFormState). I see in the Nextjs [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations#server-side-validation-and-error-handling) that they recommend using the built in useFormState, but when I see people build apps with the new version of Nextjs a lot of them use the react hook useForm.

Im trying to understand the benefit of both. I do notice that some validate on both ends client and server side when using useForm with zod, but it seems like with the use of useFormState and just validating on the server is easier and produces the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t tell you anything about `useForm`. But `useFormState` has only one purpose. Provide information (return value) from form actions (Next.js Server Actions). This is handy for example if you mutate server state and want access feedback (results) from the server action.

Answer (score 0):

```
"use client";
import { useFormState } from "react-dom";

async function increment(previousState: any, formData: FormData) {

  return previousState + 1;
}
export default function StatefulForm({}) {
  const [state, formAction] = useFormState(increment, 0);
  return (
    <form>
      {state}
      <button formAction={formAction}>Increment</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).